# curly Brackets Converted to Character Escape Code when setting cookie via nuxt js

Tags: cookies, yii2, nuxt.js

I have two web pages, one is running from php and other from nuxt js. I have already set up cookie from php side and now I want to use and manupulate the value of cookie on nuxt platform and again set up with same name. I am using cookie-universal-nuxt plugin to set cookies.

Now I am facing a problem here that my cookie set up by php looks like below :

{%22name%22:%22vandana%22%2C%22email%22:%22vvv@dfdf.com%22%2C%22display_city%22:%22Jakarta+Selatan%22%2C%22city%22:%22jakarta-selatan%22%2C%22city_id%22:%22146%22%2C%22subCityId%22:%22%22%2C%22subCityName%22:%22%22%2C%22mobile%22:%22847387483%22%2C%22alternateMobile%22:%22%22%2C%22lead_type%22:%2270%22%2C%22brandSlug%22:%22toyota%22%2C%22modelSlug%22:%22kijang-innova%22%2C%22variantSlug%22:%22%22%2C%22preferDay%22:%227%22%2C%22preferTime%22:%22%22%2C%22purchaseOption%22:%22%22}

and my nuxt cookie is setting up like beolw:

%7B%22city%22%3A%22%22%2C%22display_city%22%3A%22display_city%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22pincode%22%3A%22%22%2C%22locality%22%3A%22%22%2C%22subCityId%22%3A%22%22%2C%22subCityName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22vandan%22%2C%22mobile%22%3A%228423847324%22%7D

Means curly brackets and colons are being encoded by uriencoded scheme automatically in nuxt js. So because of this my default functionality on php is not working correctly as cookie is set with different value. I want my js to set cookie exactly as php is doing.

Here is my code of js I am using to set cookie:

```
this.$cookies.set(
  'gd_uc',
  JSON.stringify({
    city: cityData.city,
    display_city: cityData.display_city,
    id: cityData.id,
    pincode: '',
    locality: '',
    subCityId: '',
    subCityName: '',
    name: cityData.name,
    mobile: cityData.number
  })
```

Comment: What plugin are you using for managing your cookies?

Comment: @JairReina: cookie-universal-nuxt    https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt

Answer (score 0):

I see, the problem you have is that the plugin you're using uses encodeURIComponent as the default function for encoding, so you will have to use your own function to get the output format that you need (to match what PHP is doing)

Thankfully, you can pass your own encode function as part of the options of the set function. It's the third parameter of the set function:

```
this.$cookies.set( 'gd_uc', data, { encode: function(){...}}
```

What I would do is something like this:

```
this.$cookies.set(
  'gd_uc',
  JSON.stringify({
    city: cityData.city,
    display_city: cityData.display_city,
    id: cityData.id,
    pincode: '',
    locality: '',
    subCityId: '',
    subCityName: '',
    name: cityData.name,
    mobile: cityData.number
  }),
  encode: function(value){
    // 1. remove the { and } characters
    // 2. pass the resulting string to encodeURIComponent
    // 3. Add { and } to the beginning and the end of your string
    return `{${encodeURIComponent(value.replace(/[\{\}]/g,''))}}`;
  }
)
```

Hope that helps!